# Using IfDefine with environment variables

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, environment-variables

I am trying to make my configuration as flexible and easy-to-configure as possible by using a list of variables in `/etc/sysconfig` and loading the environment variables when Apache is started using a systemd drop-in configuration file. Since the environment variables don't change after the server is started, I want to improve performance and flexibility by using Apache's `IfDefine` directive instead of the regular `If` directive.

One of the problems with the regular `<If>... </If>` directive is that the directives inside the block are always *evaluated* even if they are not *executed*. This is very important if you are using environment variables as parameters, like this:

```
SVNParentPath ${MY_SVN_REPOSITORIES_PATH}
```

In this case, Apache will throw an error and refuse to start if `${MY_SVN_REPOSITORIES_PATH}` evaluates to an empty string. I want to disable serving repositories when the system environment variable `MY_SVN_REPOSITORIES_PATH` is empty or not set. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an ugly hack, but it will work. What we do here is we use the `Define` directive to define a variable whose *name* includes the *value* of the environment variable, then check if that variable is defined:

```
Define "Test${MY_SVN_REPOSITORIES_PATH}"
<IfDefine Test>
    # the variable is set to an empty string
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !Test>
    # SVN repositories are configured or the variable is unset
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine "Test/srv/svn">
    # SVN repositories are configured to be in /srv/svn
</IfDefine>
```

If `${MY_SVN_REPOSITORIES_PATH}` evaluates to an empty string, the configuration parameter "Test" will be defined. If the environment variable evaluates to something else (possibly the literal `${MY_SVN_REPOSITORIES_PATH}` if the environment variable is unset) then the configuration parameter "Test" (by itself) will not be defined.

There is one limitation here: we can test for *specific values*, including an empty string, but we cannot test for whether the variable is unset using only the `IfDefine` directive. This is because there is no way to put the literal dollar-sign and brackets characters into a an `IfDefine` directive without having Apache try to expand them<sup>1</sup>. Without an escape character, you'll never know whether Apache is comparing with the literal variable name or its value.

But, there's an ugly hack to work around that, too!

```
# Prevent environment variable expansion by splitting the variable name into two literals
Define FirstPartOfVariableName "${MY_SVN_"
Define SecondPartOfVariableName "REPOSITORIES_PATH}"

Define "Test${MY_SVN_REPOSITORIES_PATH}"
<IfDefine "Test">
    # Environment variable is set to an empty string
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine Test${FirstPartOfVariableName}${SecondPartOfVariableName}>
    # Environment variable is not set
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !Test>
    <IfDefine !Test${FirstPartOfVariableName}${SecondPartOfVariableName}>
        # The environment variable is set, and is not an empty string.
    </IfDefine>
</IfDefine>
```

Here, we've circumvented the environment variable expansion so that we can identify the three main cases we care about during configuration. You can't combine `IfDefine` directives with an OR operation, so "not set" and "empty string" are stuck being separate blocks, but you can either copy and paste your configuration between the blocks or check out [mod_macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_macro.html).

---

1. I checked Apache's source code. The function is `ap_resolve_env` in `core.c`, and the functions that call it seem to only disable the call when a compile-time switch is set.